Convert string to array<string> without using regexp
Is there a way to convert a string like [R55, B66] back to array<string> without using regexp?
The Set-up
In this output, we see codes column is StringType. StringType is required for the output but is making consuming the output more challenging for users.
Sample Input Data
input_data = """[{
   "id":"1234",
   "code":"R55"
},{
   "id":"123",
   "code":"B66"
}]"""
input_df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([input_data]))

How the Table was created
output_df = input_df.groupBy('id').agg(F.array_agg('code').alias('codes'))
output_df = output_df.withColumn('codes', F.col('codes').cast("string"))




id
codes




1234
[R55, B66]



# schema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codes: string (nullable = false)

The Concern
regexp seems to be the only option to convert the string column back into array<string>
What Works
df = output_df.withColumn('codes_array', F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(codes, '(\\w+)', 1)"))




id
codes
codes_array




1234
[R55, B66]
[R55, B66]



# schema
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- codes: string (nullable = false)
 |-- codes_array: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

What Does Not Work
Example 1 - returns NULL
schema = T.ArrayType(T.StringType())
df = output_df.withColumn('codes_array', F.from_json(F.col('codes'), schema))\




id
codes
codes_array




1234
[R55, B66]
NULL



# schema
root
 |-- ServiceActivityID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- correction_codes: string (nullable = false)
 |-- codes_array: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

Example 2 - Returns Error Message
schema = T.ArrayType(T.StringType())
df = output_df.withColumn('codes_array', F.from_json(F.col('codes'), schema, {'mode': 'FAILFAST'}))


Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.BadRecordException:
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token
'R55': was expecting (JSON String, Number (or 'NaN'/'INF'/'+INF'),
Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

The Question(s)
Is there a way to read the codes column back to array<string> without using regexp?
Or is there a way to make codes column write to a StringType format that works with a non-regexp function (like from_json)?
(With my current approach it seem that spark is happy to convert types in 1 direction, but does not set them up in an format that enables them easily be converted back. Is there a better approach to take for this table read/write given the StringType constraint?)

The string generated by directly using cast('string') is not a standard JSON string. You can use the to_json function to generate a standard JSON string, and then use from_json.
df = df.withColumn('codes', F.to_json('codes'))
df = df.withColumn('codes_array', F.from_json('codes', 'array<string>'))


Thanks this worked! to_json outputs string , and the output is a format that allows me to then use from_json to get back to array<string>
